# Laravel add attribute in collection and display it in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have troubles adding a property to every item in a Laravel collection and then displaying it in my Vue.js component.

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $tousLesBons = BonCadeau::with(['user', 'moyendepaiement'])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $changed = $tousLesBons->map(function ($value, $key) {
        $value['residualAmount'] = 50;
        return $value;
    });

    return $changed->all();
}
```

Axios in Vue.js (works)

```
fetchBonsCadeaux()
        {
            axios.get('/bonCadeaus')
            .then((res) => { 
                this.bonCadeaux = res.data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        },
```

Display in my Vue.js table (same place as axios)

```
<tr v-for="bonCadeau in bonCadeaux" :key="bonCadeau.id">
      <td>{{bonCadeau.serialNumberProduct}}</td>
      <td>{{bonCadeau.cost}}</td>
      <td>{{bonCadeau.amountOfCard}}</td>
      <td>{{boncadeau.residualAmount}}</td>
      <td>{{bonCadeau.moyendepaiement.name}}</td>
      <td>{{bonCadeau.user.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

The displaying part of my also work if I remove the `residualAmount` property. I can't get my head around this error.

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'residualAmount' of
>   undefined"

Comment: The error means that `boncadeau` is undefined... the value is not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have miss spelled a variable. Don't forget that, variables are case sensitive.

This `<td>{{boncadeau.residualAmount}}</td>`

should be this:

`<td>{{bonCadeau.residualAmount}}</td>`